# Run and Pause an ARSession in a specified period of time

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit, dispatch-queue

I'm developing `ARKit`/`Vision` iOS app with gesture recognition. My app has a simple UI containing single `UIView`. There's no `ARSCNView`/`ARSKView` at all. I'm putting a sequence of captured `ARFrames` into `CVPixelBuffer` what then I use for `VNRecognizedObjectObservation`.

I don't need any tracking data from a session. I just need `currentFrame.capturedImage` for `CVPixelBuffer`. And I need to capture ARFrames at 30 fps. 60 fps is excessive frame rate.

> **`preferredFramesPerSecond`** instance property is absolutely useless in my case, because it controls frame rate for rendering an `ARSCNView`/`ARSKView`. I have no ARViews. And it doesn't affect session's frame rate.

So, I decided to use `run()` and `pause()` methods to decrease a session's frame rate.

**Question**

I'd like to know how to automatically `run` and `pause` an ARSession in a specified period of time? The duration of `run` and `pause` methods must be **`16 ms`** (or 0.016 sec). I suppose it might be possible through `DispatchQueue`. But I don't know how to implement it.

How to do it?

[image]

Here's a pseudo-code:

```
session.run(configuration)

    /*  run lasts 16 ms  */

session.pause()

    /*  pause lasts 16 ms  */

session.run(session.configuration!)

    /*  etc...  */
```

P.S. **I can use neither CocoaPod nor Carthage in my app**.

**Update**: It's about how ARSession's `currentFrame.capturedImage` is retrieved and used.

```
let session = ARSession()

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    session.delegate = self
    let configuration = ARImageTrackingConfiguration() // 6DOF
    configuration.providesAudioData = false
    configuration.isAutoFocusEnabled = true            
    configuration.isLightEstimationEnabled = false
    configuration.maximumNumberOfTrackedImages = 0
    session.run(configuration)  

    spawnCoreMLUpdate()
}

func spawnCoreMLUpdate() {    // Spawning new async tasks

    dispatchQueue.async {
        self.spawnCoreMLUpdate()
        self.updateCoreML()
    }
}

func updateCoreML() {

    let pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer? = (session.currentFrame?.capturedImage)
    if pixelBuffer == nil { return }
    let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer!)
    let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: ciImage, options: [:])
    do {
        try imageRequestHandler.perform(self.visionRequests)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? If you want the session to update, there might be a method to do that. You could also use [session(_:didUpdate:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessiondelegate/2865611-session), which gets called every frame. (You'll need to implement the session delegate)

Comment: Could you share the code where `currentFrame.capturedImage` is retrieved and used? If I understand your question correctly, you want some kind of timer to call this every 32ms. Also, if you don't need tracking information, it sounds like `AVCaptureSession` could be a better fit to capture frames as `CVPixelBuffer`.

Comment: Thanks @Sparga. I tried `AVCaptureSession`. Energy impact is approximately the same, so I prefer `ARSession` for my app (because it's simpler). ARSession's frame rate is 60 fps by default. I need 30 fps.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the update, it's helpful. One more question, are you using the`session(_ :didUpdate:)` delegate? Because I don't get how your `updateCoreML()` is called 60 times per second otherwise.

Comment: I updated my question. No I'm not using the `session(_ :didUpdate:) delegate`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the `run()` and `pause()` strategy is the way to go because the DispatchQueue API is not designed for realtime accuracy. Which means there will be no guarantee that the pause will be 16ms every time. On top of that, restarting a session might not be immediate and could add more delay.

Also, the code you shared will at most capture only one image and as `session.run(configuration)` is asynchronous will probably capture no frame.

As you're not using `ARSCNView/ARSKView` the only way is to implement the `ARSession` delegate to be notified of every captured frame.

Of course the delegate will most likely be called every 16ms because that's how the camera works. But you can decide which frames you are going to process. By using the timestamp of the frame you can process a frame every 32ms and drop the other ones. Which is equivalent to a 30 fps processing.

Here is some code to get you started, make sure that `dispatchQueue` is not concurrent to process your buffers sequentially:

```
var lastProcessedFrame: ARFrame?

func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
  dispatchQueue.async {
    self.updateCoreML(with: frame)
  }
}

private func shouldProcessFrame(_ frame: ARFrame) -> Bool {
  guard let lastProcessedFrame = lastProcessedFrame else {
    // Always process the first frame
    return true
  }
  return frame.timestamp - lastProcessedFrame.timestamp >= 0.032 // 32ms for 30fps
}

func updateCoreML(with frame: ARFrame) {

  guard shouldProcessFrame(frame) else {
    // Less than 32ms with the previous frame
    return
  }
  lastProcessedFrame = frame
  let pixelBuffer = frame.capturedImage
  let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, options: [:])
  do {
    try imageRequestHandler.perform(self.visionRequests)
  } catch {
    print(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such a great and detailed answer.

Answer (score 5):

If what you want is to reduce the frame rate from 60 to 30, you should use the `preferredFramesPerSecond` property of `SCNView`. I'm assuming you're using an `ARSCNView`, which is a subclass of `SCNView`.

[Property documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnview/1621205-preferredframespersecond)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand It correctly, you can achieve it via DispatchQueue. If you run below code, It prints HHH first then waits for 1 second then prints ABC. You can put your own functions to make it work for you. Of course change time interval from 1 to your desired value.

```
let syncConc = DispatchQueue(label:"con",attributes:.concurrent)

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
syncConc.async {
    for _ in 0...10{
        print("HHH - \(Thread.current)")
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1)
        print("ABC - \(Thread.current)")

    }
}
```

PS: I'm still not sure If Thread.sleep will block your process, If It is I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Emre!