# How to get "light-invariant" `capturedImage` in ARKit?

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit

I want to stitch multiple background images provided by ARKit ([`ARFrame.capturedImage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arframe/2867984-capturedimage)). (I know there are better ways to do this task, but I am using my custom algorithm.)

The issue is that the live stream does not have locked exposure and thus the color of an object in the scene depends on how I orient my iPhone. This, for example, leads to a wall having very different color in each frame (from white through gray to brown-ish), which creates visible banding when stitching the images together.

I noticed ARKit provides [`lightEstimate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arframe/2878306-lightestimate) for each `ARFrame` with the [`ambientIntensity`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arlightestimate/2878308-ambientintensity) and [`ambientColorTemperature`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arlightestimate/2921629-ambientcolortemperature) properties. There is also the [`ARFrame.camera.exposureOffset`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera/3194569-exposureoffset) property.

Can these properties be used to "normalize" captured images so that colors of the objects in the scene stay roughly the same throughout time and I don't end up with severe banding?

P.S. I do need to use ARKit, otherwise I would set-up my own session based on the `AVFoundation` API with my own settings (e.g. locked exposure).

Comment: Martin, Did you find a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi Martin, I am also wondering whether you found a way to solve this issue. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I haven't solved this issue yet.

Answer (score 1):

Since all mentioned properties are not settable you can't use them directly to fix an intensity of every stitched image in panorama-360.

But you can calculate a difference of intensity and exposure of each frame and then use that multipliers for `CoreImage` filters. For instance, exposure difference is as simple as that:

```
Frame_02_Exposure / Frame_01_Exposure = 0.37
```

Then use the result as input multiplier for [CIExposureAdjust](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIExposureAdjust) filter.

Comment: Andy, how do you calculate intensity and exposure for each frame?

Comment: Hi @Gogo123, try these – let session = ARSession();

let expOffset = session.currentFrame?.camera.exposureOffset;

let ambientLightExtimate = session.currentFrame?.lightEstimate;

ambientLightExtimate?.ambientIntensity;

let dirLightExtimate = session.currentFrame?.lightEstimate as? ARDirectionalLightEstimate;

dirLightExtimate?.primaryLightIntensity; To calculate current and next frame use this approach – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53685090/run-and-pause-an-arsession-in-a-specified-period-of-time

Comment: hi @AndyFedoroff - if you're there I have a quick question, I invited you to a chat!  kindly fattie

Comment: thanks @AndyFedoroff . As I'm currently working with YCbCr or RGB colors, do you know where I could find some magical formulas that would adjust the colors given  intensity and exposure differences for each frame? Thanks!

Comment: @Gogo123, are you working with AVFoundation? The better path here is to publish a separate question on SO, containing all the code you've written.